# C structure initialization from Python code

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I have a Python program that has a ctypes.Structure equivalent of the following C structure:

```
struct Contxt
{
    unsigned int gprs[16];
    unsigned int loopnum;
    int exec_once;
    ...
    ...
}Ctxt;


Contxt = 
{   
    {0x90000000, 0x12345678, 0xE7FD702D, 0xF1C5B959, 0x7BAD0B98, 0x6F9A9A6E, 0x75D108C7, 0xD26C2E25, 0xF3008DBE, 0xF99C1A16, 0x3A3B81B6, 0x7A7117A8, 0x8115DA62, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff},
    7527,
    0
}
```

However, I need this ctypes structure to get converted into an actual C structure (say in a .h file) and also dump out its initialization (as illustrated above) from my python program.

Is there already a library that converts a ctypes to a C struct? Further, Is there a way where the Python code and the C code can share the same structure to avoid me to maintain it as a ctypes?

Any other suggestions/ideas will also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. Do you just want to know how to initialize a C struct in python and then call C functions on it, or is this about how to generate header files containing code based on data structures?

Comment: [pycparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser) can emit C for an AST.

Comment: @amaurea:Basically I am looking for a simple and neat way to generate a C structure .h and its initialization .c code like the one shown above from Python.